# Ударение в слове "поняв"

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно произносится: *пОняв* или *понЯв*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно говорить "пон***я***в" - на приставки в русском языке ударения, как правило, не ставятся.

Answer (score 1):

Деепричастие "поняв" образовано от глагола "понять" с ударением на Я.